# R: Show sources of install.packages

Tags: r, install.packages

I would like to read the source files of the `install.packages` function. More specifically, I'd like to understand exactly how this function downloads files from web repositories.

However, these source files seem hidden (`debug(install.packages)` is useless). Do you have any idea how i can access them? BTW I thought hiding source files was something not commonly done in R...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running in RStudio, there are two functions with that name:  the wrapper that RStudio put in place, and the original one from the `utils` package in base R.

You can see the original one by typing

```
utils::install.packages
```

The source is really long, so I won't post it.

You can see the RStudio replacement by leaving off the prefix:

```
> install.packages
function (...) 
.rs.callAs(name, hook, original, ...)
<environment: 0x7f856709ec00>
```

Seeing what they put in their hook is a little trickier:

```
get("hook", envir = environment(install.packages))
```

It's not completely clear what you want to find from the source, but at some level R is going to use the `download.file()` function to download things.  You can debug that to see what files it downloads.